# Find keys in the dictionary with the largest date by masks

Tags: python

How I can get the keys from the ftp_json dictionary with the largest date by mask from the daily_updated list?

```
daily_updated = ('kgrd', 'cvhd', 'metd')

ftp_json = {'kgrd0118.arj': 'Jan-18-2007', 
 'kgrd0623.arj': 'Jun-23-2005', 
 'kgrd0624.arj': 'Jun-24-2005', 
 'cvhd0629.ARJ': 'Jan-29-2021', 
 'cvhd1026.arj': 'Oct-26-2015', 
 'cvhd1125.ARJ': 'Nov-25-2019', 
 'cvhd0222.ARJ': 'Feb-22-2022',
 'metd0228.ARJ': 'Feb-28-2022',
 'metd0321.ARJ': 'Mar-26-2021',
}


result = ['kgrd0118.arj', 'cvhd0222.arj', 'metd0228.ARJ']
```

Comment: What do you mean 'by mask'. A mask usually refers to a sequence of bits used for bitwise operations, but your data is all strings, not integers.

Comment: I mean that "mask" = value in the daily_updated list. For example, value 'kgrd' in the ftp_json include date in the end of name ('krgd0102', 'krgd0103' etc). My mask in example is 'krgd'.

Comment: is "mask" just the first 4 characters of the key?

Comment: Yes, mask is just first 4 chars of the key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can no doubt be done more simply, but I think this example is a descriptive way to do this with the standard library.

```py
from datetime import datetime

ftp_json = {
    "kgrd0118.arj": "Jan-18-2007",
    "kgrd0623.arj": "Jun-23-2005",
    "kgrd0624.arj": "Jun-24-2005",
    "cvhd0629.ARJ": "Jan-29-2021",
    "cvhd1026.arj": "Oct-26-2015",
    "cvhd1125.ARJ": "Nov-25-2019",
    "cvhd0222.ARJ": "Feb-22-2022",
    "metd0228.ARJ": "Feb-28-2022",
    "metd0321.ARJ": "Mar-26-2021",
}


max_dates = {}  # New dict for storing running maximums.
for k, v in ftp_json.items():
    d = datetime.strptime(v, "%b-%d-%Y")  # Use datetime for comparison.
    # Here we return the previous tuple values if set for comparison.
    # If they weren't set, do so now.
    maxk, maxv, maxd = max_dates.setdefault(k[:4], (k, v, d))
    if d > maxd:  # Update the values is the current date is more recent.
        max_dates[k[:4]] = (k, v, d)

# Validate we stored the correct values.
assert [v[0] for v in max_dates.values()] == [
    "kgrd0118.arj",
    "cvhd0222.ARJ",
    "metd0228.ARJ",
]
```

Comment: Thank you, very simple and easy to understand for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make advantage of the `key` parameter of the `max` (and `min`) built-in function to impose a ordering criterium. Before that you need to turn the string containing the dates into `datetime` objects which come along with their own ordering, `__lt__` etc, implementation. Here the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for the date formatting.

Notice that a minimum `date` object is needed, it will be used as a "fake" value to avoid interference from all other masks in the max-term search. I naturally fixed it as the minimum among of all dates.

```
import datetime

daily_updated = ('kgrd', 'cvhd', 'metd')

ftp_json = {'kgrd0118.arj': 'Jan-18-2007',
 'kgrd0623.arj': 'Jun-23-2005',
 'kgrd0624.arj': 'Jun-24-2005',
 'cvhd0629.ARJ': 'Jan-29-2021',
 'cvhd1026.arj': 'Oct-26-2015',
 'cvhd1125.ARJ': 'Nov-25-2019',
 'cvhd0222.ARJ': 'Feb-22-2022',
 'metd0228.ARJ': 'Feb-28-2022',
 'metd0321.ARJ': 'Mar-26-2021',
}


def date_formatter(mydate):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate, '%b-%d-%Y').date()

# smallest date
day_zero = datetime.datetime.strptime(min(ftp_json.values(), key=lambda d: date_formatter(d)), '%b-%d-%Y').date()

# get the maximum for each mask
m = [max(ftp_json.items(), key=lambda pair: date_formatter(pair[1]) if pair[0].startswith(pattern) else day_zero) for pattern in daily_updated]

print([i for i, _ in m])
```

Output

```
['kgrd0118.arj', 'cvhd0222.ARJ', 'metd0228.ARJ']
```

**EDIT**

To keep it more readable (and not single-line-like), a decorator can be introduced that will be passed to the `key` parameter of `max` (`min`).

```
# ...

def date_formatter(mydate):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(mydate, '%b-%d-%Y').date()

# smallest date
day_zero = datetime.datetime.strptime(min(ftp_json.values(), key=lambda d: date_formatter(d)), '%b-%d-%Y').date()

# decorator containing the logic of the comparison criteria
def ordering(pattern):
    def _wrapper(pair):
        if pair[0].startswith(pattern):
            # cast to date-object if the "mask"/pattern is correct 
            return date_formatter(pair[1])
        else:
            # return default smallest date-object -> will not influence the max-function
            return day_zero
    return _wrapper

# get the maximum for each mask
m = [max(ftp_json.items(), key=ordering(pattern)) for pattern in daily_updated]
```